# Make mi output in r reproducible

Tags: r

I am using the package "mi" in R to do multiple imputation to fill in missing data. I'm running 20 chains, and then using those chains to obtain an average estimate for each missing datum.

However, if I run the code again, I get a (slightly) different result, even if I use set.seed() outside the function or/and add seed=MYSEED to my mi call.

Is there any way I can get reproducible data, or is this not possible because of how multiple imputation works?

Example data:

```
DATA
    ID   V1   V2   V3
    107621 11.50171 16.64066 16.65306
    107681 12.76660 17.38262 16.70621
    137411 11.91239 17.11157 17.31341
    157451 11.47981 16.56674 20.06920
    166811 12.18617 17.08419 20.60378
    167771 11.82204       NA 19.46740
    176171 11.78097 16.95551 24.80159
    176591 11.86585 17.02943 17.96875
    186161 12.12046 17.07597 18.19658
    187481 11.38946 16.46817 22.58955
```

Code run 1:

```
MV_DATA<-missing_data.frame(DATA)
imp.DATA<-mi(MV_DATA, n.chains=20, seed=1204688)
MI_RESULTS<-as.data.frame(complete(imp.DATA))

MI_RESULTS_FIRST<-MI_RESULTS[6,1:5]
```

Code run 2:

```
MV_DATA<-missing_data.frame(DATA)
imp.DATA<-mi(MV_DATA, n.chains=20, seed=1204688)
MI_RESULTS<-as.data.frame(complete(imp.DATA))

MI_RESULTS_SECOND<-MI_RESULTS[6,1:5]
```

Comparison:

```
MI_RESULTS_FIRST
      chain.1.ID chain.1.V1 chain.1.V2 chain.1.V3 chain.1.missing_V2 
      167771       11.82204       17.23201        19.4674        TRUE

MI_RESULTS_SECOND
      chain.1.ID chain.1.V1 chain.1.V2 chain.1.V3  chain.1.missing_V2 
      167771       11.82204       16.93971        19.4674        TRUE
```

Desired output is Output 1 == Output 2, but this fails - the imputed value (chain.1.V2) differs between runs.

Solution (credit answers below) is to use parallel=F in the code:

```
...
imp.DATA<-mi(MV_DATA, n.chains=20, seed=1204688, parallel=F)
...
```

However, this is only a partial solution, because seed=T,parallel=T fails to produce reproducible results. This might be a bug. This has been raised with the package maintainer [PACKAGE MAINTAINER'S RESPONSE TO FOLLOW]

Comment: Please make a minimal reproducible example (code + data)

Comment: hmm, strange. I just tried using the `seed` argument, and also `set.seed` prior to running (ysing the `?mi` example) and it was not reproducible. I dont know what alg they use but I wouldnt see why it could not t be made reproducible using a seed.

Comment: Actually , try using `parallel=FALSE` and `seed=` arguments, then it is reproducible

Comment: @user20650 which I would consider a bug. Reproducibility is possible with parallel processing. This should be reported to the maintainer. He needs to put at least a warning into the documentation, but preferably this should be fixed.

Comment: @Roland, absolutely. I was just having a look at hte docs to see if there is a way to pass a seed, but I am not really familiar with `parallel`

Comment: Thank you both (and apologies for the lack of data). I will report this as a potential bug

Comment: Good stuff Joni. Can you report back if you get any updates from the maintainers  please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not reproducible based on how `mi` parallelises the chains (which it does by default). So if you set `parallel=FALSE` the `seed` argument will work (although this has a significant speed cost).

Example

```
library(mi)
# Example from ?mi
data(CHAIN, package = "mi")
mdf <- missing_data.frame(CHAIN) # warnings about missingness patterns
mdf <- change(mdf, y = "log_virus", what = "transformation", to = "identity")

imp1 <- mi(mdf, seed=1)
imp2 <- mi(mdf, seed=1)
identical(imp1, imp2)
#[1] FALSE

imp1 <- mi(mdf, parallel=FALSE, seed=1)
imp2 <- mi(mdf, parallel=FALSE, seed=1)

identical(imp1, imp2)
#[1] TRUE
```

But see comments above. <strike>1. there may be a way to somehow pass a seed across the clusters (I dont know how)</strike> 2. If not, it should be considered a bug