# Why the results of imputaion is different in package mi?

Tags: r, imputation

In package `mi` I found that the results are different per running imputation with exactly the same options. Consider the following code:

```
library(mi)
data(nlsyV)
mdf = missing_data.frame(nlsyV) 
imputations = mi(mdf, n.iter = 30, n.chains = 4, seed=123)
data1 = complete(imputations, 4)
summary(data1[[4]]$ppvtr.36) #ppvtr.36 is one of the variables with missing values and now has the imputed values
```

The results of the once running the code for variable `ppvtr.36` is:

```
 Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
41.00   74.00   87.00   86.08   99.00  132.00
```

If the code is run for once more, the results are:

```
 Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
27.96   72.89   86.50   85.58   98.86  138.60
```

Obviously the results of imputation is different for each time performing it, nevertheless the seed is fixed. Is it normal?

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input data. I cannot seem to get this to work with the built in example dataset.

Comment: try setting parallel =FALSE, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38152274/make-mi-output-in-r-reproducible